# Can I declare enums within enums to specify/limit both keys and values in a map in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, enums

I want to be able to specify a list of keys and allowed values for each key programatically so that the code can be checked at compile time for errors and in the hope of better performance.

Imagine I am representing word in a database and each word has a number of features:

```
public class Word {

  public Map<Feature, FeatureValue> features = new EnumMap<Feature, FeatureValue>();

}
```

And I have an enum class:

```
public enum Feature {

  TYPE("Type") {

    enum Value {
     NOUN("Noun"),
     VERB("Verb");
   }

   @Override
   public Value[] getValues() {
     return new Value[]{Value.NOUN, Value.VERB};
   }

 },


  PLURALITY("Plurality") {

    enum Value {
     SING("Singular"),
     PL("Plural");
   }

   @Override
   public Value[] getValues() {
     return new Value[]{Value.SING, Value.PL};
   }

 },

}
```

I would at least want to be able to do something like:

word.features.put(TYPE, TYPE.Value.NOUN);
   word.features.put(PLURALITY, PLURALITY.Value.PL);

So that it's easy to see that the values match the key, but the enum within enum syntax doesn't seem to be allowed.

I also tried this:

```
TYPE("Type") {

 public String NOUN = "Noun";
 public String VERB = "Verb";
```

but I couldn't reference TYPE.NOUN since they aren't allowed to be static for some reason.

Please is there someone who know a good pattern to specifying something like this? I'm just worried if use strings in my code like

```
word.features.put(TYPE, "Noun");
```

I am asking for trouble with typos etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it like that but you can do it like this:

```
// define a type values as an enum:
enum TypeValue {
  Noun, Verb
}

// define an attribute class parametrized by an enum:
public class Attribute<E extends Enum<E>> {

    // define your attribute types as static fields inside this class
    public static Attribute<TypeValue> Type = new Attribute<TypeValue>();
}

// and now define your method like this:
<E extends Enum<E>, Feature extends Attribute<E>> void put(Feature feature, E value) {
}

// you will then have a compilation error when trying to invoke the method with improper associated parameters.

// eg if we define
enum OtherValue { X }

features.put(Attribute.Type, TypeValue.Noun); // ok
features.put(Attribute.Type, OtherValue.X); // Fails
```

Comment: Thanks Toader! I'll give this a try. I don't quite understand though where the Feature class comes in? Couldn't I just use:
`<E extends Enum<E>, Attribute<E>> void put(Attribute<E> feature, E value) {`

Comment: It's the way i thought it initially :). If you want to make it simpler you should go all the way: `<E extends Enum<E>> void put(Attribute<E> feature, E value)`